# Button not clicking with scrapy playwright

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, playwright

I am attempting to click on an sso login for a platform by testing its button functionality with scrapy playwright. I have inputted an incorrect email and so after clicking the button, it should throw a text error that the email is incorrect. However, nothing seems to happen.

For example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod
from path import Path

class telSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tel'
    start_urls = 'https://my.tealiumiq.com/login/sso/'

    customer_settings = {
        'USER-AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/16.0 Safari/605.1.15',
        'CONNECTION': 'keep-alive',
        'ACCEPT': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            self.start_urls,
            meta = dict(
                    playwright = True,
                    playwright_include_page = True,
                    playwright_page_methods = [
                        
                        PageMethod('waitForLoadState', state = 'domcontentloaded'),
                        PageMethod("fill", selector = '#email', value = "incorrect@email.com"),
                        PageMethod('wait_for_selector', selector = "span[data-i18n='login.form.btn_submit']", state = 'visible'),
                        PageMethod("click", selector = "#submitBtn", button = "middle",  delay = 2000, force=True),
                        PageMethod("waitForEvent", event = "click"),
                        PageMethod("screenshot", path=Path(__file__).parent / "tealium.png", full_page=True),
                        ]
                ),
                callback = self.parse
        )
    def parse(self, response):
        print(response)
```

I have attempted `evaluate` instead but this for some reason will only do one or the other event. For example, it either inputs email first or clicks, not one after the other or both.

```
"""(function() {
    const setValue = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
    window.HTMLInputElement.prototype,
    "value"
    ).set;
    const modifyInput = (name, value) => {
    const input = document.getElementsByName(name)[0]
    setValue.call(input, value)
    input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true}))
    };
    modifyInput('email', "incorrect@email.com");
    document.querySelector("#submitBtn").click();
    }());"""
```

Expected output:
[image]

Comment: It worked by include `wait_for_timeout` and added an appropriate wait time. I was successfully redirected afterwards.